# Confused about anaconda and ipython

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ipython

I already have anaconda on my conputer and I want to launch ipython(shell and notebook).
According to the book I'm reading(Python data science handbook), "you’ve installed a distribution
like Anaconda or EPD, there may be a launcher specific to your system". However, I cannot find any further explanation of this.

Then I search on the internet. On the ipython website https://ipython.org/install.html ,it is said that "For new users who want to install a full Python environment for scientific computing and data science, we suggest installing the Anaconda or Canopy Python distributions, which provide Python, IPython and all of its dependences as well as a complete set of open source packages for scientific computing and data science." This means that anaconda has already contained ipython. However, I just cannot find it(or,maybe,don't know how to find it).

Then I look for methods to get ipython in anaconda, but all explanations I've seen on the internet are incomprehensible to me, They just say "do what what" and then finish. I want a more detailed explanation that don't omit any step(even though it may seem easy for you).

Also, I think I'm confused about the concepts,"jupiter notebook","ipython notebook" and "ipython shell"(I even don't know what is a notebook and what is a shell). I can see a "jupiter notebook" when I open my anaconda.

Comment: Jupyter Notebooks were named IPhyton Notebooks some time ago.
The IPython shell offers you a way to run python code. It's like a terminal and it will execute your code when you hit enter. Normally you would write python scripts and execute them. If you are familiar with terminal and bash files, that may be a good comparison.

A notebook offers a slightly different way to execute your code:
- instead of executing whole scripts or single lines, it offers the possibility of splitting your script into various cells which can be executed independetly.

Comment: @raphael_mav Thank you very much for your explanation! So what I'm looking for is exactly the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: It depends on your work. You can execute python code in multiple different ways.
IMHO jupyter notebooks may work best when you want to get started, since they offer a easy way to test code blocks.
Just search for a Jupyter tutorial on youtube, I'm sure you'll understand if it's useful for your specific task.

Comment: @raphael_mav Thanks very much! Now I think I understand these things better.

Answer (score 1):

[The IPython Notebook is now known as the Jupyter Notebook.](https://ipython.org/notebook.html)
Notebooks offer a way to execute Python code cell-wise. That means you can split up your code in various cells and execute them independently.

[The IPython shell offers one way to execute Python commands.](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-interective-shell) It waits for user input and as soon as the command was entered, it executes it and prints the result.

I'd suggest you to watch a few tutorials about Jupyter Notebooks and IPython Shell to evaluate which approach suits your needs better.